# I can not write normal filter in wireshark filter input

Tags: wireshark, traffic-filtering

Why I can not write normal filter in wireshark filter input?

[image]

you see I write the filter:

```
ip.src==192.168.2.228
```

there seems do not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field you are in is looking for a Capture Filter, which uses a different syntax than a display filter. The Capture Filter you are looking for is:

```
host 192.168.2.228
```

That will capture only traffic to or from IP address 192.168.2.228.

Once you have packets captured, you can use a Display Filter to further filter them. For a Display Filter, your example syntax is correct.

```
ip.src==192.168.2.228
```